# Is it possible to bypass Android lock screen using accessibility service programmatically?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am developing a scheduling application. I am using accessibility services to accomplish the task. After a certain duration of time, the phone wakes up with the desired activity and using accessibility services, the task is accomplished.

My code works fine when there is no pattern/pin lock, i.e. there is only a slide lock. When there exists a pattern/pin lock, the user needs to unlock the phone for the activity to open up and the task to occur. This defeats the whole purpose of scheduling and automating the task for the future.

I understand that this is security breach but it is somehow being done in the following applications: [SkipLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benhirashima.skiplock) and [Unlock With WiFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwifitrial).